# Particles unaffected by force fields

Tags: particles, force-fields

I'm trying to create a water scene where paper lanterns rise from the background (similar to [this scene](https://youtu.be/9mayDR-PlXo?t=27s) from the movie Tangled.

I'm using a particle system to generate a bulk of lanterns to rise from behind some (really bad for now) hills. The issue is that they just won't budge in the face of any type of force field. Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here?

I set up another file and emulated the situation and things are working perfectly, so I must be making some dumb mistake that I can't see with my tired eyes.

[Link to .blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/39071)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make lanterns being affected you should increase the mass of your particles and decrease the *Gravity* in the Force Field settings.

#### Clear the Effector Group

First thing to change is to clear the *Effector Group* in the **Field Weights** options (or create another group from the force fields). From the [wiki](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/particles/physics/introduction.html#field-weights):

> The Field Weight Panel allows you to control how much influence each type of external force field, or effector, has on the particle system.

Thus the effector is the one who *affects* on the particles, *not* the one who is *being affected*. And in your file, the group which contains meshes and lamp was set as effector.

#### Increase the mass of the particles

In the **Physics** scroll increase the mass of the particles. As they were too lighweight they began to fly away immediately.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the perfect explanation! You are right on the money.